# Script onload - call internal function

Tags: javascript, html

In my app, I'm using a script tag to load an externally-hosted JS script. This script defines a function which I want to call on the frontend when it's loaded, and to pass certain variables. So you could imagine this file looks something like this:

```
window.someFunc = (args) => {
  // do something
}
```

And then in my frontend HTML:

```
<script src="/someFile.js" onload="someFunc('hello')"></script>
```

This works, but if I change `window.someFunc` to `const someFunc`, it no longer works, because the `onload` doesn't have access to `someFunc`. It seems to me non-ideal that I have to attach the function to the window object. Is there a way to avoid this and still access this function in the `onload` of the script tag?

I know this question seems pretty basic, but I've done a number of searches and can't find an answer about how to do this neatly.

Comment: What is the order of including the `<script>` tags? That might be one reason I guess.

Comment: This is the only script tag. It pulls in the external JS file, and has the onload attribute, which only has access to the function within the JS file if the function is attached to the window object. Is that unexpected? I'm including it at the end of the body element.

Comment: I can't replicate this behaviour; mine works fine. Is the `script` in the `body` or the `head`?

Comment: Is the code that defines the function inside another function? If so, `someFunc` is only visible in the scope of that function, but `onXXX` code runs in the global scope.

Comment: Also, maybe it's what you're doing in `someFunc` that doesn't work immediately `onload`? What exactly do you mean by "no longer works"?

Comment: I just mean that if I change `window.someFunc` to `const someFunc` and reload the page, it stops working. The function is *not* scoped inside another. Well, it's good to know it's something on my end. I'll debug, thanks.

Comment: Maybe it's a browser-specific issue? I'm testing on Chrome 79.0.3945.88, if that helps your debugging. My script tag looks like `<script src="./temp.js" onload="func('hello world')" charset="utf-8"></script>`, and my `func` looks like `const func = str => console.log(str);`. Good luck!